# using condition variable in c

Tags: c, multithreading, condition-variable

i have a multithread program written in c which has 3 threads, main thread, producer thread and consumer thread. the code uses condition variable to handle signalling and handling emitted signals. the problem is when i run the program it seems some of emitted signals are lost and doesn't catch by any handler. can someone explain these output to me?

global variables:

```
static pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

int avail = 0;
```

the producer thread:

```
static void *producer_thread(void *arg)
{   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        avail = 1;
    //    sleep(2);

        
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

        printf("sent signal#%ld from signaling thread\n", i);
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

the consumer thread:

```
static void *consumer_thread(void *arg)
{
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        
        while(0 == avail)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mtx);
        }

        printf("received signal from consuming_thread\n");
        avail = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
}
```

main thread:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t tid1, tid2;
    int rc;

    rc = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, consumer_thread, NULL);
    if(rc){
        printf("error in pthread_create form consuming_thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    rc = pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, producer_thread, NULL);
    if(rc){
        printf("error in pthread_create form signalling thread\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

sample output:

```
sent signal#0 from signaling thread
received signal from consuming_thread
sent signal#1 from signaling thread
sent signal#2 from signaling thread
sent signal#3 from signaling thread
sent signal#4 from signaling thread
sent signal#5 from signaling thread
sent signal#6 from signaling thread
sent signal#7 from signaling thread
sent signal#8 from signaling thread
received signal from consuming_thread
sent signal#9 from signaling thread
received signal from consuming_thread
```

Comment: what is the output? and also, what is the definition of avail?

Comment: @Effie the question has been updated

Comment: Usually when people post broken code for condition variables, I tell them that a condition variable is not a semaphore. Apparently when people post perfectly well-behaved code using a condition variable, I have to tell them a condition variable is not **two** semaphores.

Comment: @Effie in simple words, we have a thread which produces a signal and a thread which must catch the emitted signal properly(although my code may be wrong and i would like to help me correct it, thanks!)

Comment: @EOF you mean im using the condition variable in wrong manner?

Comment: No, you're using the condition variable correctly (which is unusual for a stack overflow question involving condition variables). It just doesn't do what you appear to think it does. The real question is: *Why* do you expect the producer thread to wait, when there is absolutely no code here that would make it?

Comment: @EOF thanks for your comment, so there is no way to change code to wait for consumer thread and then run the producer thread with condition variable? (if it isn't, i must use semaphore to achieve these functionality?

Comment: There are many ways to make a thread wait for something. You can have it wait for a semaphore, a condition variable, a signal, a pipe or any other I/O. You could replace your current synchronization with two semaphores for example, so each thread allows the other to continue at the appropriate time, and in turn waits for the other thread to allow it to continue. However, the next question is why you would use two threads if only one can ever do any significant work at the same time. Don't use multithreading if you can't accept concurrency.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One problem is that your producer thread does not verify whether `avail` is zero before setting it to one. When the condition broadcasts, that is no guarantee that the waiting consumer thread gets scheduled *immediately* or even *first*. And when it gets scheduled, it still must lock the mutex first that it relinquished when it started to wait. It is perfectly possible that the producer's loop runs a few times before that happens.

If you want to force a consumption after a production, you should make the producer check if the `avail`-able thing has been consumed, for *example* by writing your loop as follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{    
    int proceed = 0;
    while (!proceed) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        if (avail == 0) {
            avail = 1;
            proceed = 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
    printf("sent signal#%ld from signaling thread\n", i);
}
```